# Can a function who is linear in each variable separately have a degenerate critical point that is not a saddle point?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, morse-theory

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is linear in each variable $x_i$ separately but not in the vector $x$, e.g, $f(x)=2x_1x_4x_6-7x_1x_2x_3+15x_3x_5x_6$.
This family of functions always has zero diagonal hessian, hence the hessian is not definite or semi-definite. In general, the hessian can have a zero eigenvalue and hence have a degenerate critical point. However, it sounds weird that a function that is linear in each variable separately can have a minimum or a maximum point. After all, this function is monotone in each variable.
How do I classify the critical points in this case?

Comment: The sum of all the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the Hessian, which is zero. Thus, if *any* of the eigenvalues is strictly positive, another one must be strictly negative.

Comment: Yes, that much I know. The thing is that is doesn't really help me in classifying the critical point since Morse theory is for none-degenerate critical points, and here, the hessian can also have zero as an eigenvalue (in addition to sum negative and positives ones)

Comment: But ... think about this: the function in the neighbourhood of the critical point is approximated by a quadratic - taking the coefficients from the Hessian, which (via a suitable orthogonal transformation) can be diagonalised, with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. This means, if two eigenvalues are $\lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda_2<0$, once you switch to a different set of co-ordinates $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_n)$ your function looks like $\lambda_1\xi_1^2+\lambda_2\xi_2^2+\ldots+\text{ terms of higher order than }2$ - which is clearly neither a maximum nor a minimum (due to the first two terms).

Comment: (NB Here I am not addressing the case where the Hessian is a zero matrix, i.e. all eigenvalues are zero. This can happen but I have not managed to think through it yet.)

Comment: I see what you mean, but then why is MOrse Theory limited to none-degenerate points?